# Window close, using link or typing URL?

Tags: javascript, browser, window, dom-events

There is a very simple problem I haven't found any solution that solves it. Is there any way **to distinguish between**:

1. leaving the browser window (tab) **using link**
2. **typing** another **URL** to the URL bar in the browser
3. **closing** the tab or browser window

I need to bind different Javascript code for those actions. I know I can filter all links by setting them special class, but is there anything working in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't detect** external events of browser such as user's clicking on browser's close button or selecting Exit from menu or typing a new url in address bar.

You can however use `onbeforeunload` event to your advantage to do something:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  // do something
};
```

This will trigger when user navigates to other page by clicking on page's link, closing browser or leaving current page in any way.

Comment: Thanks for this feature. However, isn't there any variable (flag) that determines the performed action which I can use in this function?

Comment: @PavelS.: The `onbeforeunload` fires when user is about to leave your page in ANY way, there is nothing else associated with it unfortunately.

Comment: OK, hard luck for me. Anyway, thanks for good answer, despite it's not what I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 1):

You can't distinguish between typing a new URL or closing the window, but you could add a click event handler to all the links to check whether the user is about to navigate away using a link:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a")​;
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
        if (this.href.test(/^http[s]?:\/\//))
            //external link clicked
    };
}
```

For the others, you can use `window.onbeforeunload` (note that this event will also handle external links, so be careful not to handle them twice if you use the previous solution).
​